# Error with vagrant up for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrantfile

Triying to run vagrant up --provider=aws I get the following error.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:164:in `action': undefined method `fire_triggers' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/martin/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-aws-0.7.2/lib/vagrant-aws/provider.rb:32:in `state'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:521:in `state'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:145:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:79:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:79:in `machine'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:700:in `machine'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:180:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:204:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:186:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:186:in `with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:87:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:54:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:275:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.0/gems/vagrant-2.1.0/bin/vagrant:156:in `<main>'
```

My vagrant file is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'vagrant-aws'


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "aws-dummy"

    config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "my_key_id"
    aws.secret_access_key = "my_access_key"
    aws.keypair_name = "my_keypair_name"

    aws.ami = "ami-916f59f4"

    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa"
    end
end
```

I'm running vagrant version 2.1.0, I also installed vagrant-aws(0.7.2) plugin.

The question is what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Vagrant 2.1.0 - https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9775

Comment: Sorry, Im running host machine with: Linux linux-machine 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as suggested by [PrasadK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762073/prasadk) it seems to be a bug, not the particular one you suggested, but there is a bug in version 2.1.0.

I manually upgrade varian to 2.1.1 and the problem is fixed.